# Why does this vertex buffer object fails to Update?

Tags: c++, opengl, jquery-animate, vertex-buffer

I have the following pieces of code where I successfully create a vertex buffer object, initialize it with data, and render it using GLSL 4.0.  However, when I go to update the data stored in the vertices after animation, OpenGL gives me the error code 0x502 and does not accept my updated vertices information.

Could someone point me in the direction as to why these code does not allow my vertices information to be successfully updated?  I should also mention that sometimes, the data is successfully updated with is not always consistent/predictable.

**Data Structure used**

```
    struct Vertex3{
        glm::vec3       vtx;        //0
        glm::vec3       norm;       //3
        glm::vec3       tex;        //6 Use for texturing or color
    };

vector<Vertex3> geometry.vertices3;
```

**Initialization Code**

```
    void solidus::Mesh::initVBO(){

        geometry.totalVertexCount = geometry.getVertexCount();

        // Allocate an OpenGL vertex array object.
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayId);

        glGenBuffers(2,geometry.vboObjects);

        // Bind the vertex array object to store all the buffers and vertex attributes we create here.
        glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayId);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometry.vboObjects[VERTEX_DATA]);

        //size the size of the total vtx
        GLuint byte_size = getTotalSize();


        //Reserve the inital space for the vertex data
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, byte_size, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);


        if(geometry.isStructVertex4())
            initVBO4( );
        else if(geometry.isStructVertex3())
            initVBO3( );
        else
            initVBO2( );


        //release
        glBindVertexArray(0);


        geometry.vertices4.clear();
        //geometry.vertices3.clear();
        geometry.vertices2.clear();
    }

void solidus::Mesh::initVBO3( ){

    //getTotalSize() ==  getVtxCount() * sizeof(Vertex3);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, getTotalSize(), &geometry.vertices3[0]);

        //Note: offsetof -- c++ standard library
        //Note: glVertexAttribPointer- first parameter is location of GLSL variable
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  // Vertex4 position
        glVertexAttribPointer( (GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex3), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex3,vtx) );
        // Vertex4 normal
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer( (GLuint)1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vertex3), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex3,norm)  );
        // Texture coords
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer( (GLuint)2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex3),(GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex3,tex) );

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometry.vboObjects[INDEX_DATA]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint)*geometry.indices.size(), &geometry.indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

}
```

**Update the Mesh Vertex information** why does this fail

```
void solidus::Mesh::uploadVertexGLFx(){


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometry.vboObjects[VERTEX_DATA]);



    string e0="";
    if(geometry.isStructVertex2()){
        solidus::GLVBO::setVBOSubData(getTotalSize (), &geometry.vertices2[0]);
        e0="Vertex2";

    }else if(geometry.isStructVertex3()){
        //THIS IS THE POINT OF INTEREST: at least suspected!!!!!
        //  getVtxCount() * sizeof(Vertex3) = getTotalSize
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, getTotalSize (), &geometry.vertices3[0]);
        e0="Vertex3";
    }else {
        solidus::GLVBO::setVBOSubData(getTotalSize (), &geometry.vertices4[0]);
        e0="Vertex4";
    }
    //report error is glGetError is not equal to 0
    postMsg("failed to upload vertex for struct " + e0 , "uploadVertexGLFx",30);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Comment: Do you change the number of vertices? `glBufferSubData()` cannot change the size of the underlying buffer store.

Comment: @derhass, I did not change the sie of the vertices.  The number of vertices and the total size of the vertices remain unchanged, the only thing that changes is the vertices(x,y,z) values, which i need to inform the graphic card of.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my updateVertexGLFx function to the code listed below.  The main difference with this good is that after I resupplied the vertices information to GL, I informed OpenGL of the pointer offset using gl*AtribPointer.  Now the program reliably updates when I call my update function.

```
void solidus::Mesh::uploadVertexGLFx(){


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometry.vboObjects[VERTEX_DATA]);



    string e0="";
    if(geometry.isStructVertex2()){
        solidus::GLVBO::setVBOSubData(getTotalSize (), &geometry.vertices2[0]);
        e0="Vertex2";

    }else if(geometry.isStructVertex3()){
        //glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getTotalSize (), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
        //THIS IS THE POINT OF INTEREST: at least suspected!!!!!
        //  getVtxCount() * sizeof(Vertex3) = getTotalSize
        cout << "Total Size = " << getTotalSize() <<endl;
        cout << "Vtx Count = " << getVtxCount() << endl;
        cout << "Sizeof(Vertex3)=" <<sizeof(Vertex3)<<endl;

        Vertex3 *f = new Vertex3[getVtxCount()];
        for(int i=0; i<getVtxCount();i++){
            f[i] = geometry.vertices3[i];
        }


        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getTotalSize(), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, getTotalSize (), f);



        //Note: glVertexAttribPointer- first parameter is location of GLSL variable
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  // Vertex4 position
        glVertexAttribPointer( (GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex3), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex3,vtx) );
        // Vertex4 normal
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer( (GLuint)1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vertex3), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex3,norm)  );
        // Texture coords
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer( (GLuint)2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex3),(GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex3,tex) );

        delete f;
        f = nullptr;

        e0="Vertex3";
    }else {
        solidus::GLVBO::setVBOSubData(getTotalSize (), &geometry.vertices4[0]);
        e0="Vertex4";
    }
    //report error is glGetError is not equal to 0
    postMsg("failed to upload vertex for struct " + e0 , "uploadVertexGLFx",30);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```